# Prestashop Module - Control user postal code

Tags: php, prestashop

I am trying to develop a Prestashop module for reading the sending address postal code of the user and, depending on the code do some actions. I am beginning with the modules developing and I am a bit lost. I suppose that I have to use a certain hook, but cant find the right, could be authentication, but I am not sure.

Which is the correct hook?

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: Which is the correct hook?

Comment: "actionAuthentication" After authentication, Or
"actionBeforeAuthentication" before authentification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever a new object is saved or updated following hooks are called:

actionObjectAddBefore

actionObjectAddBefore

actionObjectAddAfter

actionObjectAddAfter

actionObjectUpdateBefore

actionObjectUpdateBefore

actionObjectUpdateAfter

actionObjectUpdateAfter

So in your case you should be able to use actionObjectAddressAddAfter.